# Biztalk "SQL" adapter raised error message

Tags: sql, biztalk

The adapter "SQL" raised an error message.details MSDTC on server "server name" is unavailable.

How can solved above error because every morning some of my SQL receive location got disable ?

Comment: So this only happens over night?

Comment: Nope it wasn't!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't add comments yet
The cluster validation tools are part of the server OS installation assuming 2008 R2 or later
If the tools haven't been used during setup the installation is unsupported by MS

Comment: I don't know real solution what happened there and I also removed answer it was posted earlier!thanks you for your comment !